# how to kill a thread abruptly from the main thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, ftplib

i have a ftp server that uses a serve_forever command. this ftp service is called in a thread ,what i want to do is that i want to abruptly close the thread from the main thread ,when i hit the stop button on my GUI.

```
import os
import sqlite3
from pyftpdlib import ftpserver
def main():
    authorizer = ftpserver.DummyAuthorizer()
    #does something
    address = ('127.0.0.1', 10221)
    ftpd = ftpserver.FTPServer(address, handler)

    # start ftp server
    ftpd.serve_forever()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

this is my main thread which calls the ftp service

```
def start_ftp(self):
    self.ftp_status.setText("Running")
    self.ftp_status.setStyleSheet("Background : light green")
    #thread.start_new_thread( FtpService )

def stop_ftp(self):
    self.ftp_status.setText("Stopped")
    self.ftp_status.setStyleSheet("Background : red")
    #what should i put here for the desired result
```

please help guys

Comment: Can you just store `ftpd` somewhere publically visible (ie, in a global) and call `close` or `close_all` from the main thread?

Comment: @Useless :thanx for the quick response , would you be kind enough to give an example  on how to execute the above given answere

Comment: You don't want to abruptly close a thread. You want to stop your FTP service. Thinking about the work rather than the execution vehicles is the first step to writing sensible multithreaded code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : any book or material that you would recommend for  multi-threaded programming in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/wiki/Tutorial#2.4_-_Server_(acceptor)), `close_all` should "Stop serving ...", so `serve_forever` should return.

Store your `ftpd` object in a global variable (currently it is local to `main`), you can call `close` or `close_all` from the main thread.

---

Per your comment, the steps are:

1. make `ftpd = ftpserver.FTPServer(address, handler)` refer to a [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4693120/212858)
2. call `ftpd.close_all()` when you want to stop serving ftp connections